# Return a list of items after Observable is complete

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java

I need to return a list of items but before that I have to check for some particular ones. I'm able to do that only async.

```
fun getItemList() : List<Model> {
val list = mutableListOf<Model>()
list.add(model1)
list.add(model2)

Observable.fromCallable { findParticularModel() }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(object : Observer<String> {
            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable?) {

            }

            override fun onNext(modelId: String) {
                list.add(createModelFromId(modelId))
            }

            @SuppressLint("TimberExceptionLogging")
            override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                Timber.e(e?.message)
            }

            override fun onComplete() {

            }

        })

return list
}
```

How can I return the list only after the `Observable` is completed

Comment: If `getItemList` runs on the main thread, it is impossible as it would deadlock. You'd have to turn this into a `Single<List<Model>>` and keep composing.

Comment: @akarnokd, yes the `getItemList` was intended to be called on the main thread. Can you please provide a solution?

Comment: You need to redesign the whole `getItemList()` to be asynchronous, not only its contents. There are technical ways to wait for the list to become ready to be returned, but if you do this, the code would be equivalent to just something like `return findParticularModel()` - without all this async stuff. Whatever you wanted to do with the resulting `list` after returning it, you need to do this in `onComplete()`. Your function can't return the list and at the same time work asynchronously.

Comment: Or, you can switch to a background thread somewhere earlier in the call stack and then make this function fully synchronous (so remove Rx stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to create and consume such asynchronous datasource:

```kotlin
fun getItemList() : Single<List<Model>> {
    Single.fromCallable { findParticularModel() }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map {
             val list = mutableListOf<Model>()
             list.add(model1)
             list.add(model2)
             list.add(createModelFromId(it))
             list
        }
        
}

getItemList().subscribe({
    // here you have $it as list on the main thread
}, {
    Timber.e(it?.message)
})
```